# Network manager with NSURLConnection

Tags: iphone

I am trying to create something like a Network Manager using NSUrlConnections.
For that, I want to be able to send multiple requests, but I also want to be able to identify the client(delegate) that made the request when the response arrives. 
I have created a NSDictionary like this:

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:SERVER_TIMEOUT];
....
[clients setObject:client forKey:connection];
```

in "- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection" I have something like this:

```
client = (id<RTANetworkDelegate>)[clients objectForKey:connection];
[clients removeObjectForKey:connection];
```

The Network Manager is the delegate for all the connections, I do some preprocessing and then I send the (parsed) response to the right delegate, that sent the request in the first place.

Unfortunately, it appears that a NSMutableURLRequest cannot be set as a key in a dictionary since it does not have the copyWithZone method and I get the error:

> -[NSURLConnection copyWithZone:]:
>   unrecognized selector sent to
>   instance

Any help would be much appreciated! 
Thanks!

=======================================

[Edit] I already found this in the meantime:

http://blog.emmerinc.be/index.php/2009/03/15/multiple-async-nsurlconnections-example/

It seems to solve my problem.. I still don't know if it's the best solution though. I thought I would post it here since it might help others too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the `-hash` value of the connection object as the key:

```
[clients setObject:client forKey:[connection hash]];
```

I'd stay away from the actual URL or anything similar as two requests could potentially have the same URL.

Comment: What would happen if the two connections were identical (yet may get different data from the cloud), wouldn't the -hash return the same value for both of them? By definition of the NSObject protocol -hash should return the same value for the both of them 'If two objects are equal (as determined by the isEqual: method), they must have the same hash value.' I assume that isEqual: will return YES for two NSURLConnections that look a like.

Comment: The two NSURLConnections will be different (they'll have different pointers) so isEqual will return false and the hash value will also be different.

Comment: Cheers for clearing that for me, I suspected so, but somehow I assumed isEqual: compares content not pointers.